# How to set processosor affinity for apache service?

Tags: windows, apache, wsgi, affinity

I have several apache instances running on a windows machine and to avoid IO bottlenecks caused by Python's GIL, I need to set the affinity of apache's worker process.

Apache writes the PID of its main watchdog process, but the PID of the process containing the embedded WSGI (modwsgi) is never written.

Short of restarting one service at a time to find the new WSGI PID and setting its affinity, is there a better way of either recording the PID of the WSGI process, or some way of flagging the apache service to use a predefined affinity?

Answer (score 0):

There is no separate mod_wsgi process on Windows. The WSGI application runs inside of the Apache child process, the same process that static files requests are handled.

Comment: When starting a single apache service on windows, there are two running processes. Only one of those has its PID recorded. I need to set the affinity for the other process, which is the one that does all of the work for the request (hosts modwsgi and executes the python code).

Comment: I know what you want, just saying that the second process is standard Apache process and not a mod_wsgi specific process. You might learn something from http://www.fmc-modeling.org/category/projects/apache/amp/4_3Multitasking_server.html#SECTION00635000000000000000